# Why does the removal of "+-" cause the whole function to not work ?

Tags: jquery

Code is as shown below.

```
$('p:first').toggle(function() {
$(this).animate({'height':'+=150px'}, 2000, 'linear');
}, function() {
$(this).animate({'height':'-=150px'}, 2000, 'swing');
});
```

Comment: if you want to remove `-` and `+`, you should remove `=` too, and it will work.

Comment: Please show the version of the code that doesn't work so we remove questions about what you're asking.  Your question as written now is not very clear (thus why it's getting downvoted).

Comment: Wow, in 11 mins, you all closed a question from a new user that just needs a clarification about what exactly they're asking.  You guys are harsh.  There is a real question in here - this user just didn't communicate it very well.  At least give them a few minutes to clarify what they meant to ask.

Comment: @jfriend00: If there is a discernibly real question here, you can edit it and vote to reopen. Your answer was a guess at best, and it even attracted a downvote that could not be adequately justified precisely because of how vague the question is. We want good answers to good questions, not unconfident answers to unclear questions... guesswork isn't always going to work out for the asker, the answerer(s) as well as future readers, hence the NARQ close reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change both attributes to "150px" by removing the `+=` and the `-=`, then both sides of your toggle are animating to the same height so there will be no visual movement.  It might move to 150px when you first hover, but then it won't move again.

The point of the `+=150px` is to add 150px to the existing height whatever it is.  The point of the `-=150px` is to subtract 150px from the existing height (thus reversing the prior addition).

If you want to remove the `+=` and the `-=`, then you need to set two different heights in the two arms of the toggle to define the two sizes that you want to toggle between.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is what I thought the OP was asking.  It is a poorly worded question, but this was my best guess as to what they meant.

Comment: I think the question is just asking about removing the operator, not the equal sign... and I *think* that would make it invalid and cause it to not work at all.

Comment: This is why vague questions should be closed ASAP - not only are answers not verifiable by anyone other than the OP, but neither can the downvotes be fully justified. Strange, isn't it? (I wasn't the downvoter — I don't downvote answers to bad questions unless the answers are equally bad :)

Comment: @BoltClock - IMO, when we see vague questions from fairly new users we should explain to the new user what needs to be clarified so they can learn how to write better questions rather than just throwing it back in their face with no coaching about what they need to do better.  If you don't have the desire to do that, you can just ignore the question and move on.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I do have a habit of letting the close reason speak for itself instead...

Comment: Sorry for the poorly worded question. Guess I wansn't thinking too clearly just now. Yes, this is what I am looking for. Thanks @jfriend00 .

Comment: @jfriend00 - What does it mean by version of code ? Is it referring to the jQuery Version I am using ?

Comment: @TheKraven - No.  I mean that you need to post the actual code that doesn't work so it's absolutely clear to us what it is.  You posted code that works and then tried to describe some change to that code.  We didn't understand.  If you just post the actual code that doesn't work, there would have been no confusion.

Comment: Oh! Noted, will do that the next time round =)